# How to update modified_at column on a root entity when child changed?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is there a way to tell hibernate to change `modified_at` column on root entity whenever child entity change ?
I have over 60 database tables. There is one root entity. Whenever I change any table I need to propagate that change to root entity and update `modified_at` column.
 `Cascades` work the other way root -> child. I need child -> root.
 What's the best way to approach this problem ? Any sugestions ? I have read about `Event Listeners` but I find it too complicated for my use case. I couldn't come up with something more elegant, easier to implement. Any suggestions how to approach ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using `Event Listeners` inspired by [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). I created 2 listeners one for insert and one for update / delete. They intercept changes and whenever change occur I update `modified_at` column on root entity.

```
@Component
public class RootAwareInsertEventListener implements PersistEventListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RootAwareInsertEventListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PERSIST).appendListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Intercept hibernate persist - and if entity is RootAware it will update modified_at of root entity
     */
    @Override
    public void onPersist(PersistEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        final Object entity = event.getObject();

        if (entity instanceof RootAware) {
            RootAware rootAware = (RootAware) entity;
            MortgageCase root = (MortgageCase) rootAware.root();
            logger.info("Modifing {} modified_at because a {} child entity has been inserted", root, entity);
            root.setModifiedAt(new Date());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPersist(PersistEvent event, Map createdAlready) throws HibernateException {
        onPersist(event);
    }
}

@Component
public class RootAwareUpdateAndDeleteEventListener implements FlushEntityEventListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RootAwareUpdateAndDeleteEventListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.FLUSH_ENTITY).appendListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Intercept hibernate update / delete - and if entity is RootAware it will update modified_at of root entity
     */
    @Override
    public void onFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        final EntityEntry entry = event.getEntityEntry();
        final Object entity = event.getEntity();
        final boolean mightBeDirty = entry.requiresDirtyCheck(entity);

        if (mightBeDirty && entity instanceof RootAware) {
            RootAware rootAware = (RootAware) entity;
            if (updated(event)) {
                MortgageCase root = (MortgageCase) rootAware.root();
                logger.info("Modifing {} modified_at because a {} child entity has been updated", root, entity);
                root.setModifiedAt(new Date());
            } else if (deleted(event)) {
                MortgageCase root = (MortgageCase) rootAware.root();
                logger.info("Modifing {} modified_at because a {} child entity has been deleted", root, entity);
                root.setModifiedAt(new Date());
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean deleted(FlushEntityEvent event) {
        return event.getEntityEntry().getStatus() == Status.DELETED;
    }

    private boolean updated(FlushEntityEvent event) {
        final EntityEntry entry = event.getEntityEntry();
        final Object entity = event.getEntity();

        int[] dirtyProperties;
        EntityPersister persister = entry.getPersister();
        final Object[] values = event.getPropertyValues();
        SessionImplementor session = event.getSession();

        if (event.hasDatabaseSnapshot()) {
            dirtyProperties = persister.findModified(event.getDatabaseSnapshot(), values, entity, session);
        } else {
            dirtyProperties = persister.findDirty(values, entry.getLoadedState(), entity, session);
        }

        return dirtyProperties != null;
    }
}
```